# Emacs ECB - Saving and restore process

Tags: python, emacs, emacs-ecb

I've tried the past few days build by myself a fully functional Python IDE with Emacs and ECB.
The last step I'm trying to reach is to save the ECB session with all ongoing process (like Python Shell and Backtrace buffer).

I've tried with windows.el and revive.el but both can't restore ECB and process, they only restore the file and the windows' splits positions & sizes.

Does anyone has an idea how to do this for save the schema above?

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|ECB path w|                                       |
+----------|                                       |
|ECB W0    |            My python file             |
+----------|                                       |
|ECB W1    |                                       |
+----------|---------------------------------------+
|ECB W2    |    *Backtrace*     |   Python Shell   +
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can try `workgroups2` extension https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2 but it has an open issue about ECB. If you drop a comment there - I'll spend more time on this problem.

Comment: I've got a strange error output: `This \`cl-labels' requires \`lexical-binding' to be non-nil [4 times]
or: Wrong number of arguments: #[(cl-item cl-seq cl-start &optional cl-end cl-from-end)` plus a lot of randoms symbols.
I guess this is because I'm running emacs 23 on Debian Wheezy.
Workgroups2 seems to be a recent fork and might be only compatible with emacs24...

Comment: yes, that's true, I didn't test it on 23, sorry